# R neural package : cannot run the mlp example?

Tags: r

I'm trying to learn the neural package that i think is simple compared to others. I tried to run the following example that is given in the correspending documentation :

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/neural/neural.pdf  ( page 5 ).

```
library(neural)

x<-matrix(c(1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0),4,2)
y<-matrix(c(0,1,1,0),4,1)
neurons<-4
data<-mlptrain(x,neurons,y,it=4000)
mlp(x,data$weight,data$dist,data$neurons,data$actfns)
```

The script produces this error :

```
Error in if ((!visual) | (coor$x > 640) & (coor$x < 700) & (coor$y > 650) &  : 
  argument is of length zero
Calls: mlptrain
Execution halted
```

Session info :

```
sh: 1: cannot create /dev/null: Permission denied
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.0

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] neural_1.4.2.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.4
Error in if ((!visual) | (coor$x > 640) & (coor$x < 700) & (coor$y > 650) &  : 
  argument is of length zero
Calls: mlptrain
Execution halted
```

The problem is that I cannot visualize the predicted and observed values.
Thank you for help in advance !

Comment: plz could someone help with an example of how to use 'mlptrain' and 'mlp' for neural package ?

Comment: Hi Tou, your example works fine for me... try to run that in a new R session or provide `sessionInfo()` output here, maybe there will be some problem...?

Comment: @Petr Kajzar , for me the example gives some plotting of the neural network but i cannot compare actual/predicted data.  Also i can't visualize what data object contains

Comment: @PetrKajzar , i updated the post !